Modular arithmetic inside a modulus RNS
so I have those numbers, let's call them $ x $ and $ y $ and I want to implement modular arithmetics between $ x $ and $ y $ over the range $ [\![ 0,N) $ using the residue number system (RNS) with a modulus $ M = p_1 p_2 p_3 $, $ M \geqslant N $ .
I managed to get the subtraction right using a function that returns parity.
It works as long as $ p_1,p_2,p_3 $ are odd.
It's likely possible to do something similar with the addition but there are more cases to consider because we need to determine whether $ x+y $ is in the range $ [\![ 0, N), [\![ N, M),[\![ M, 2N),[\![ 2N, 2M) $ and it is a bit cumbersome.
Could it not be easier to do change from representatives of $ x $ and $ y $ in the range $ [\![ 0, M) $ to representatives in the range $ [\![ N, M+N ) $ such that the rest is the value of $x+y$ when $x+y \geqslant N $ and then subtract $ N $ or maybe on the opposite shifting to a range $ [\![ N-M, N ) $  and then have a look to whether it is negative or positive ? I am not sure how to do it.
The other solution to determine $r_{Ni} = (x+y \mod N) \mod p_i $ for $i \in 1..3 $ would be to search brute force for the same $ \lfloor {\frac {x+y}{N} }\rfloor $ since $ r_{Ni} \equiv r_i - \lfloor {\frac {x+y}{N} }\rfloor r_{Np_i} \mod p_i  $  for each $ i $ but it is not very elegant
I'm a bit curious about the downvote.Please express yourself.
